# windows 10 home basic feature error

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I am using Windows 10 Home Edition, but when I start any android emulator like Bluestacks or Android Studio's emulator it shows hyper-v is detected but disabled, and they are not starting.

Also HAXM is not installing.

Error message:

[image: error message]

Windows settings:

[image: my windows features]

System details:

[image: my system details]

Comment: From your second image, it looks like you need to reboot, enter the system setup (BIOS) and enable hardware virtualization.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , but it is already enabled